# Running Selenium with IE

Tags: selenium

Can someone pls help with this

```
 package IEProjects;

    import java.io.File;

    import org.junit.BeforeClass;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class TestIEBrowser {


              static String driverPath = "IE driver path";
              public WebDriver driver;             


                @BeforeClass
                public void setUp() {
                    System.out.println("my IE");
                    System.out.println("launching IE browser");
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\IEDriverServer_Win32_3.3.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");

                    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                    driver.manage().window().maximize();
                }

                @Test
                public void testGooglePageTitleInIEBrowser() {
                    driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
                    String strPageTitle = driver.getTitle();
                    System.out.println("Page title: - "+strPageTitle);
                    Assert.assertTrue(strPageTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("Google"), "Page title doesn't match");
                }

                @AfterClass
                public void tearDown() {
                    if(driver!=null) {
                        System.out.println("Closing IE browser");
                        driver.quit();
        }

    }
    }
```

here is the error below, i appreciate your prompt reply.

> FAILED: testGooglePageTitleInIEBrowser
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at IEProjects.TestIEBrowser.testGooglePageTitleInIEBrowser(TestIEBrowser.java:32)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
>         at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
>
> ```
> ===============================================
>     Default test
>     Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
> ===============================================
>
> ===============================================
> Default suite
> Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
> ===============================================
> ```

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to debug to tell what value the variables on line 32 have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is because driver is not initialized properly.

I think you are incorrectly import beforeClass annotation from Junit instead of testNG, and thus causing setUp method not called and resulting driver not initialized

please change import into `import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;`

Answer (score 1):

The IE browser is not able to launch due to the annotation being wrong wherein you have used the JUNIT annotation instead of TestNg.